# Embed change src with target on link

Tags: html

With an iFrame and a html link, I can use the TARGET property of html links and setting a name for the iframe to change the src of the iframe.  This works well...

How can I do this same thing with an embed instead of an iframe?

So i am starting with

`<embed name="test1" src="http://www.example.com"></embed>`

The embed is inside an object class if that helps.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to edit your post, and prefix any code with 4 blank spaces so it shows up in a code block. Then we can see it :)

Comment: please use the proper example in your question.

Comment: would you be more clear? & explain what exactly you want to do with some piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript :)

```
<a onclick="document.getElementById('emb').src='whatever'">Whatever</a>
<a onclick="document.getElementById('emb').src='whatever2'">Whatever2</a>
<embed id="emb" src="default"></embed>
```

Comment: No javascript allowed becaue there are 100 links.  Any pure html or css way?

Answer (score -2):

No, you can't. Just use an iframe.